# When will strcmp not return -1, 0 or 1?

Tags: c, strcmp

From the man page:

> The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal
>   to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found,
>   respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Example code in C (prints `-15` on my machine, swapping test1 and test2 inverts the value):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* test1 = "hello";
    char* test2 = "world";
    printf("%d\n", strcmp(test1, test2));
}
```

<strike>I found [this code](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/longdup.c) (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560037/effcient-way-to-find-longest-duplicate-string-for-python-from-programming-pearl/13560449#13560449)) that relies on the values of strcmp being something other than -1, 0 and 1 (it uses the return value in `qsort`). To me, this is terrible style and depends on undocumented features.</strike>

I guess I have two, related questions:

- Is there something in the C standard that defines what the return values are besides less than, greater than, or equal to zero? If not, what does the standard implementation do?
- Is the return value consistent across the Linux, Windows and the BSDs?

**Edit:**

After leaving my computer for 5 minutes, I realized that there is in fact no error with the code in question. I struck out the parts that I figured out before reading the comments/answers, but I left them there to keep the comments relevant. I think this is still an interesting question and may cause hiccups for programmers used to other languages that always return -1, 0 or 1 (e.g. Python seems to do this, but it's not documented that way).

FWIW, I think that relying on something other than the documented behavior is bad style.

Comment: You're misunderstanding Bentley's code -- there's nothing in there that assumes anything about `strcmp`'s return value other than its sign.

Comment: "I found this code that relies on the values of strcmp being something other than -1, 0 and 1.". I don't see how that code *relies* on anything about the return values of `strcmp`. On the contrary, the code does not rely on any specific return values, which is actually very good style. So, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: The requirements for a `qsort()` comparator are that it returns "an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero" which is _exactly_ what `strcmp()` does. There's no abuse of any sort going on.

Comment: The -15 you're seeing is the result of subtracting ASCII char 119 (`w`) from ASCII char 104 (`h`). So `104 - 119 = -15`. I'd suspect that if you change `test1` to `jello` you'll get a result of `-16` and so on. The man  page you quoted specifically says "less than"; it doesn't say anything about "-1". IOW, a value less than zero would be any negative number except zero, and a value greater than zero would be any positive number except zero.

Comment: @larsmans - Yup, caught that about 5 minutes after posting... Must have been some bad cheerios in the morning... I feel like such a noob...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the C99 standard, [§7.21.4.2 The `strcmp` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.21.4.2):

> The `strcmp` function returns an integer *greater than, equal to, or less than zero*,
>   accordingly as the string pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`.

<sup>*Emphasis added.*</sup>

It means the standard doesn't guarantee about the `-1`, `0` or `1`; it may vary according to operating systems.

The value you are getting is the difference between `w` and `h` which is `15`.

In your case `hello` and `world` so `'h'-'w' = -15 < 0` and that's why `strcmp` returns -15.

Comment: This technically answers my question. I'm still marginally interested in behavior across systems, but it's not really important.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there something in the C standard that defines what the return values are besides less than, greater than, or equal to zero?

No. The tightest constraint is that it should be zero, less than zero or more than zero, as specified in the [documentation of this particular function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html).

> If not, what does the standard implementation do?

There's no such thing as "the standard implementation". Even if there was, it would probably just

```
return zero, less than zero or more than zero;
```

:-)

> Is the return value consistent across the Linux, Windows and the BSDs?

I can confirm that it's consistent across Linux and OS X as of 10.7.4 (specifically, it's -1, 0 or +1). I have no idea about Windows, but I bet Microsoft guys use -2 and +3 just to break code :P

Also, let me also point out that you have completely misunderstood what the code does.

> I found this code (taken from this question) that relies on the values of strcmp being something other than -1, 0 and 1 (it uses the return value in qsort). To me, this is terrible style and depends on undocumented features.

No, it actually doesn't. The C standard library is designed with consistency and ease of use in mind. That is, what `qsort()` requires is that its comparator function returns a negative or a positive number or zero - exactly what `strcmp()` is guaranteed to do. So this is not "terrible style", it's perfectly standards-conformant code which does not depend upon undocumented features.

Comment: If someone relies on `strcmp` returning -2 or +3 then his/her code deserves to be broken. ;-)

Comment: This answer is good, but @Omkant's answer answers both parts. +1 anyway because this answer explains my error very clearly.

Answer (score 4):

> • Is there something in the C standard that defines what the return values are besides less than, greater than, or equal to zero? If not, what does the standard implementation do?

No, as you mentioned yourself the man page says `less than, equal to, or greater than zero` and that's what the standard says as well.

> • Is the return value consistent across the Linux, Windows and the BSDs?

No.

On Linux (OpenSuSE 12.1, kernel 3.1) with gcc, I get `-15`/`15` depending on if `test1` or `test2` is first. On Windows 7 (VS 2010) I get `-1`/`1`.

Based on the loose definition of `strcmp()`, both are fine.

---

> ...that relies on the values of strcmp being something other than -1, 0 and 1 (it uses the return value in qsort).

An interesting side note for you... if you take a look at the  [`qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) man page, the example there is pretty much the same as the Bell code you posted using `strcmp()`.  The reason being the comparator function that `qsort()` requires is actually a **great** fit for the return from `strcmp()`:

> The comparison function must return an integer **less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero** if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to guess that most, if not all, unices return the difference between the characters. Interesting that Windows doesn't.

Comment: @tjameson - yeah, they actually list it out in the .asm file of `strcmp` on windows how it will work: `; The instructions below should place -1 in eax if src < dst,
        ; and 1 in eax if src > dst.` Don't know why they chose to do that instead of just return the subtracted value

Answer (score 1):

In reality, the return value of `strcmp` is likely to be the difference between the values of the bytes at the first position that differed, simply because returning this difference is a lot more efficient than doing an additional conditional branch to convert it to -1 or 1. Unfortunately, [some broken software](http://www.mysql.com) has been known to assume the result fits in 8 bits, leading to [serious vulnerabilities](https://communities.coverity.com/blogs/security/2012/07/19/more-defects-like-the-mysql-memcmp-vulnerability). In short, you should never use anything but the sign of the result.

For details on the issues, read the article I linked above:

https://communities.coverity.com/blogs/security/2012/07/19/more-defects-like-the-mysql-memcmp-vulnerability

Comment: Beware: as of 2020-011-17 01:11:00 -07:00 (don't ask), (a) the communities.coverity.com links have a certificate from misc.synopsis.com (and Synopsis.com now seems to own Coverity) so Chrome gives you (valid) scare messages about an insecure connection, and (b) the site is 'down for maintenance'.  That might be short or long term maintenance — it will require further testing.  It may be necessary to find the information in the WayBack Machine.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strcmp.html) page:

> The strcmp() function compares the string pointed to by s1 to the string pointed to by s2.
>   The sign of a non-zero return value is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of bytes (both interpreted as type unsigned char) that differ in the strings being compared.

[Here](http://freebsd.active-venture.com/FreeBSD-srctree/newsrc/libkern/strcmp.c.html) is an implementation of **strcmp** in **FreeBSD**.

```
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Compare strings.
 */
int
strcmp(s1, s2)
    register const char *s1, *s2;
{
    while (*s1 == *s2++)
        if (*s1++ == 0)
            return (0);
    return (*(const unsigned char *)s1 - *(const unsigned char *)(s2 - 1));
}
```

Comment: This looks like the behavior I'm seeing, and is probably the same as the default Linux implementation.

Comment: I don't think that there is a thing like "the default Linux implementation." `strcmp()` is part of the standard library of the compiler in use, not the operating system in use. However, most on the Linuxes use GCC in one or another version - that might differ. Nowadays Clang gains some share. And then there are several cross compilers, at least on my (Linux) system.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page:

> RETURN VALUE
>          The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes
>   thereof) is found, respectively, to
>          be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

It only specifies that it is greater or less than 0, doesn't say anything about specific values, those are implementation specific i suppose.

> CONFORMING TO
>          SVr4, 4.3BSD, C89, C99.
>   This says in which standards it is included. The function must exist and behave as specified, but the specification doesn't say anything about the actual returned values, so you can't rely on them.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the C standard that talks about the value returned by `strcmp()` (that is, other than the *sign* of that value):

> **7.21.4.2 The strcmp function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The strcmp function compares the string pointed to by s1
> to the string pointed to by s2.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal
> to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is
> greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.

It is therefore pretty clear that using anything other than the sign of the returned value is a poor practice.