# Fast way to find substring in text using suffix array and lcp

Tags: python, arrays, string, full-text-search, suffix-array

I'm trying to find words which contains substring (as input) in huge text.
The text looks like this: *america*python*erica*escape*.. 
Example: Input: "rica" => Output: america,erica

I use suffix array.

My pseudocode (pythonlike) is:

```
firstChar=input[0] // the first character of input
suffixArray=getSuffixArray(text) // suffix array
result=[]

for every index of suffix array which points to firstChar:
    length=len(input)
    indexText=text[suffixArray[index]]
    indexes=[]

    if input in text[indexText: indexText+length]:
        word=find whole word containig this index between '*' 
        result.append(word)
```

This works, but it is too slow. LCP array should improve a runtime of algorhitm but I can't figure out how. Will you give me an advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A free Python code for suffix array is at [Effcient way to find longest duplicate string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13693834/448474). It works up to 100 million characters on a personal computer.