# String slicing big O

Tags: python, string, big-o, object-slicing

```
for i in range(n):
    print("HelloWorld"[i:])
```

Is this O(n) or should I count the slicing as running over the characters of "HelloWorld"?

Also, when I compare two strings `s1==s2` does this operation run over each letter in `s1` and compare it with each letter of `s2` so O(max(len(s1),len(s2))?

Comment: Linear with respect to what? String length or slice size?

Comment: The string's length

Comment: Then, no, I don't believe it is linear.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the indexing operation would depend on the way that the string is stored. In most cases, it is just a sequence of characters, each the same length, so indexing can be done in a single operation — hence, O(1) — by directly accessing the *n*th character.

However, in some cases, indexing may be more expensive; for example, some unicode strings can have characters of different sizes, in which case the only way to find character *n* is to start from the beginning and add up the individual character sizes, in which case it really is O(n).

All together, we then have to add *n* of those individual operations as we do `for i in range(n)`, which gives another factor of *n*  — note that this is the case even though for the second case it's O(1+2+3+4+...+n) which is O(n^2) since the sum is n*(n+1)/2. (In this case, you would probably use a somewhat different algorithm to still be able to perform this task in O(n), if efficiency is important.)

Comment: Note that `[i:]` is a slice not an index.

Comment: Yes, but its complexity is just that of finding the location of character `i`.

Comment: Are you sure? [`str` slices, in general, copy...  `str` do not slice by referencing a view of a subset of the data.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35181399/68587)

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case, for understandable but slightly annoying reasons (in this case, at least).

Answer (score 0):

String slicing is an O(*k*) operation where *k* is the size of the slice. That makes your program O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) since the slice sizes are *n*/2 on average.

Equality is O(min(len(*s1*), len(*s2*))). *min* not *max*. Once it hits the end of either string it's done.