# Pop a substring from end of string efficiently

Tags: python, string, slice

Say I have a `big_string` of length `n` and I want to remove a substring of length `k` from its end

we can do it as `big_string[:-k]`, but this will be of `O(n-k)`, can we do better than this, something like in`O(k)`?

Comment: `big_string[:-k]` is not `O(n-k)`, what makes you think that? It's essentially a constant operation (`O(1)`) - either "write a null-terminator at this memory address", or "copy a defined amount of memory from one place to another and update a pointer" or some other thing that executes exactly once, regardless of the values of `n` or `k`.

Comment: List slicing is the idiomatic way to do this in python, and you're not really gonna find anything more efficient (or if you are, it'll be really ugly and non-pythonic). If you're looking for raw speed, use C or something.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180377/time-complexity-of-string-slice

Answer (score 0):

If your string is py2 `unicode` or py3 `str`, the `memoryview` idea that @MyNameIsCaleb pointed to won't work, and slices will indeed make copies, which is O(n).

Trimming the end is fast for mutable types (`del m[-k:]`), but only string types (which are immutable) support string operations like `find()`, `in`, and regular expressions.

If trimming the end is a very frequent operation, and using string operations is rare or can be bounded to a small portion of the string, it might be worth the trouble to convert the string once to a list of characters:

`chars = [c for c in big_string]`

To use string operations on bounded portions, you could convert a slice to a string. For example, to determine whether 'foo' occurs in the last 1000 characters:

`'foo' in  ''.join(chars[-1000:])`