# Return a copy of a string with indices inside a list replaced by a character

Tags: python, string

Say I have a list `indices`. I also have a character `char`. The third argument is a string `string`. I want to return a copy of `string` such that `string[index] = char` for all `index in indices`.

I do have a function that does this, but I believe that it is inefficient. It is

```
newString = string
for index in indices:
    newString = newString[:index] + char + newString[index+1:]
```

The first line makes a copy of the string. Then it iterates through all indices that need to be changed and makes the index equal to `char`.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180377/time-complexity-of-string-slice/35181399), the efficiency of slicing a string is `O(n)`, which would then make the efficiency of the above code `O(nm)`, where `n` is the length of the string, and `m` is the length of `indices`. I was hoping for a faster solution.

Any improvement would be appreciated.

Edit: An example would be with `string = "qwertyuoip", indices = [0, 4, 5, 8], char = "1"`. Then the 0th, 4th, 5th, and 8th character of string would be replaced with char. The output should be `newString = "1wer11ui1p"`.

Comment: Make your string a list (`list(string)`), operate on the list and `join()` the list again.

Comment: Why not use simple string indexing? If `char` is always a single character (len 1), then slicing is unnecessary, no?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile You can't change an index of a string because strings are immutable.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated You’re right, how did I not remember that......

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a mutable list:

```py
def replace_indices(s, indices, char):
    chars = list(s)
    for i in indices:
        chars[i] = char
    return ''.join(chars)
```

The solution has three parts:

- Build a list of characters from the string `s`. This takes O(*n*) time, where *n* is the length of `s`.
- Iterate over the list of indices, setting the character `char` at each index in the list. This takes O(*m*) time, where *m* is the length of `indices`.
- Join the list to produce the output string. This takes O(*n*) time to build a string of length *n*.

The total time is O(*n* + *m*). This is optimal, because the problem requires building a string of length *n*, and you have to use all *m* indices in the list. If the indices are always distinct, then *m* <= *n* and the time is O(*n*).