# Efficient lazy slicing in Python

Tags: python, performance, slice, lazy-evaluation

I am looking into optimizing an existing Python module that has a lot of byte-copying code like the following going around:

```
byte0 = data[0]
do_something_with_rest(data[1:])
```

And sometimes:

```
first_bytes = data[:4]
last_bytes = data[-4:]
do_something_with_rest(data[4:-4])
```

I wanted to try and avoid the many memory copies I imagine happening under the hood. To this end, I have written the `BaseStrRange` class below to do lazy slicing. This will allow the consumer to do lazy slicing without actually slicing it until use.

```
class BaseStrRange:
    def __init__(self, s, start=0, stop=None):
        self.s = s
        self.l = len(s)
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __len__(self):
        l = self.l if self.stop is None else self.stop
        l -= self.start
        return l

    def __bool__(self):
        return len(self) > 0

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if not isinstance(i, slice):
            if self.stop is not None and self.start + i >= self.stop:
                raise IndexError()
            if i < 0:
                l = self.l if self.stop is None else self.stop
                return self.s[l + i]

            return self.s[self.start + i]

        if i.step is not None:
            raise NotImplementedError()
        if i.stop is None:
            stop = self.stop
        else:
            stop = i.stop
            if stop < 0:
                l = self.l if self.stop is None else self.stop
                stop = l + stop
            else:
                stop = min(self.start + stop, self.stop or self.l)
        start = self.start + (i.start or 0)
        return BaseStrRange(self.s, start, stop)

    def apply(self, value):
        return value[self.start:self.stop]

class BytesRange(BaseStrRange):
    def __bytes__(self):
        return self.s[self.start:self.stop]
```

To understand it, consider the following:

```
>>> x = BytesRange(b'0123456789')
>>> bytes(x[1:-1][1:-1]), x[1:-1][1:-1].s
(b'234567', b'0123456789')
```

That is, the internal `bytes` object is never sliced until the `BytesRange` is explicitly cast into `bytes`. However, this code performs poorly when comparing to string copies. (The following uses VS Code cell mode notation)

```
# %%
def do_something_with_rest(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    s0 = s[0]
    return s0 + do_something_with_rest(s[1:])
# %%
%timeit do_something_with_rest(b'0123456789' * 100)
# %%
%timeit do_something_with_rest(BytesRange(b'0123456789' * 100))
```

The pure `bytes` copying object gives:

```
1e+03 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

while `BytesRange` fares worse:

```
4.78 ms ± 72.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I assume that even if I re-write the entire module, I will eventually have to do the same in-Python math that `BytesRange` does thus hurting performance instead of improving it.

My question: is there a way to beat the memory-copying code?

Comment: What times do you get for let's say `b'0123456789' * 1000` or `b'0123456789' * 10000`?

Comment: you really should use a `memoryview`...

Answer (score -1):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35181399/404861). Using Python's `memoryview` you get rid of copies, which in my use-case resulted in a 5% performance increase.